# How can I get content of a file from git index?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-status

I have a file which has been already added to my local repository. I've modified it in the working tree, so `git status` shows me the file as modified. I would like to know what is the *file content* kept in the index before I stage the file.

I can think of two ways of doing that:

1. revert a patch generated by [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), and apply it on the file in the working tree
2. use [`git checkout-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index), point to a temporary file and read the content from there

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use the `:` prefix to access objects in the current index (staged but not yet commited).

```
git show :file
```

See the [gitrevisions manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem) for more information.

Comment: I didn't see such syntax mentioned in `git show` document. Is it some kind of a hack?

Comment: @smwikipedia, [see gitrevisions(7) for more information.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hOUGa.png)

Comment: Use `git show :./file` for relative paths

Answer (score 10):

To cat a file out of the index, I’m not sure of a preexisting scriptable way, but you can use `ls-files` to query the index:

```
$ git ls-files -s README
100644 67cfeb2016b24df1cb406c18145efd399f6a1792 0   README
$ git cat-file blob 67cfeb2016b24df1cb406c18145efd399f6a1792
# etc.
```

You can put the commands together like this:

```
git cat-file blob $(git ls-files -s README | awk '{print $2}')
```

(Although surely I am reinventing the wheel here.)

However, if you just want to open the original and your changes in an editor, use the [`difftool`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html) command. It copies the indexed version to a temporary file for you and opens `vimdiff` (or anything you want), and it is very flexible.

Answer (score 4):

There are Three ways of getting diffs with git

[image: git diff graph]

so to see what the difference is between the file in the working directory and the index you just need to:

```
git diff name_of_file
```

I've written about this in more detail [elsewhere](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/474079664/whats-the-difference-part-1)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not interested in getting a diff. I'm looking for the whole _file content_. Having the diff I can deduct what was the file content before I made the change, but I already mentioned that in the question.