# Git: Show content of file as it will look like after committing

Tags: git, bash

After reading [Git pre-commit hook : changed/added files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412450/git-pre-commit-hook-changed-added-files), the following question arose:

Given I have a file with both staged and unstaged changes, how can I display a preview of the file's contents after staging?

**Example:**

```
echo "foo" >> file
git add file
echo "bar" >> file
```

Wanted output:

```
[previous contents of file]
foo
```

Comment: Wouldn't `cat file` show you the current working copy of `file`?

Comment: Yea it's the right solution - or it was a wrong question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get content of a file from git index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032188/how-can-i-get-content-of-a-file-from-git-index)

Comment: @Delan: `cat file` would bring up `bar`, which is not what I want.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It shows `foo`, then a line break, then `bar`. http://i.imgur.com/uGwgq.png

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use the `:` prefix to access objects in the current index (staged but not yet commited).

```
git show :file
```

See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem) (which uses the term 'stage 0' for the "normal" index contents):

> ```
> :[<n>:]<path>, e.g. :0:README, :README
> ```
>
> A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged.

Comment: Very nice indeed, however I'd prefer something that works with relative paths. Even though the docs state that `A path starting with ./ or ../ is relative to current working directory.`, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: So given a dirty file README; `HEAD:README` shows file before changes. `:README` shows file with staged changes only. Is there any way to show the file with only non staged changes? I didn't see anything that would indicate so in the linked documentation.

Comment: @JDIsaacks: Not directly, no, because such a file does not exist anywhere in the repository (while `:README` exists in the index and `HEAD:README` exists in the current commit). You could, however, try applying `git diff README` output (which only shows unstaged changes) to a temporary copy of `HEAD:README`...

Comment: I'm not having luck with `git show :file` if the file has not been previously committed. Is this expected? I had to fall back to `git ls-files -s <file>` and then `git cat-file -p <objHash>`.

Comment: Note that the syntax is now (has long been) formalized as `:<digit>:<path>`, where the digit indicates which index *slot* to use: 0 (zero) is the slot containing the file that will be committed, while slots 1, 2, and 3 are used only during a merge conflict.

Comment: @torek: Both `:path` and `:0:path` are documented in git's manual. The former is even listed both under `rev:path` (":path (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case") _and_ under `:n:path` ("A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry").

Comment: True - I'm suggesting that the answer could note that there's a fuller syntax to get at any of the possible index slots. (But the link to `gitrevisions` is probably sufficient)

Answer (score 6):

*Update: the [answer from grawity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153199/git-show-content-of-file-as-it-will-look-like-after-committing/5153379#5153379) has a much neater solution*

This recipe is from [jleedev's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032188/how-can-i-get-content-of-a-file-from-git-index/5032436#5032436):

```
git cat-file blob $(git ls-files -s file | awk '{print $2}')
```

You might want to create a [git alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) for that if you're going to use it often.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately, my search didn't bring up that other question.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: thanks, but I think grawity's answer is better, and the one that should be accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do git diff --cached, but this isn't exactly what you want.

`git grep -h --cached ^ -- file`

works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Just have a look at the top answer for this question: [How do I show the changes which have been staged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged)

The `--cached` option is what you want.

Comment: This will show the ***the diff*** of the staged file, but it won't show you the way the file would look if you just opened it in an editor or `cat` it.

Comment: Apologies for the downvote, but that's a perfectly good answer to a completely different question!  :smile: