# Git cat staged file to stdout

Tags: git, git-add

I have staged parts of a file in git like so

```
git add --patch ./file
```

I would like to output the contents of the staged file to stdout.

Note that the staged file and the file in the working directory are different since I only staged parts of the file.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153199/git-show-content-of-file-as-it-will-look-like-after-committing

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. sorry about the duplicate!

Answer (score 12):

If you want to just output the complete file in its staged version, you can use the syntax [suggested by grawity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153199/git-show-content-of-file-as-it-will-look-like-after-committing/5153379#5153379) in answer to a recent question:

```
git show :file
```

... or if you want to see the changes between HEAD and the index for that file (typically the changes you've just staged) you can use:

```
git diff --cached -- file
```

Comment: I'm not having luck with `git show :file` if the file has not been previously committed. I had to fall back to `git ls-files -s <file>` and then `git cat-file -p <objHash>`.