# Show file content from index

Tags: git

I added a file to the index. And edit this file in working tree. There is two different versions of the file.
I want to see version from index.

How to do it easiest?

==============
Duplicates:
[How can I get content of a file from git index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032188/how-can-i-get-content-of-a-file-from-git-index) 
[Git: Show content of file as it will look like after committing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153199/git-show-content-of-file-as-it-will-look-like-after-committing)

Comment: To be clear: you wan't to see the file, or diff against it?

Comment: I want see whole file

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get content of a file from git index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032188/how-can-i-get-content-of-a-file-from-git-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git show :file
```

shows the version of `file` in the index. It prints it out or pipes it to your configured pager.

Alternatively, you can check out the index version to a temporary subdirectory with something like:

```
git checkout-index --prefix=tmp/ file
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git diff --cached <path to file>`.
This will show you the differences which are on the index.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Comment: Yes, it shows difference, but I need see whole file content. Do you now how to do it?

Comment: @AleksYa Use `git show :<path-to-file>` then. This will print the indexed version of the file on the console.

Comment: @AleksYa Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153199/git-show-content-of-file-as-it-will-look-like-after-committing) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned - once you adding file to the index you can continue and modify it while the indexed version remains unchanged.

In order to view the index content you have to use

```
git show :<file>
```

The : are mandatory and you must have them in your cli command